# Activerecord: How to navigate from one object to the other in a Belongs_to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The relationship between User and Exercise is that user **has_many** exercise while exercise **belongs_to** user

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 attr_accessible :act_id, :bcalor, :comment, :day, :week, :duration

 before_save :calor_burned

 private

 def calor_burned
  act = Activity.find(act_id)
  #how to find user_id?
  #User has_many weeklyweight
  #and weeklyweight belongs to a user 
  wt = (Weeklyweight.where(:week => week, :user_id => user_id).first).weight
  if(wt < 180)
    self.bcalor = ((wt * act.w160 * duration)/60)
   elsif ((wt >= 180) && (wt < 220))
    self.bcalor = ((wt * act.w200 * duration)/60)
   else
    self.bcalor = ((wt * act.w240 * duration)/60)
   end
  end 
 end
```

How do I access the **user.id** which help me access the weight?

## EDIT

I'm trying

```
user = act.user
```

I'm getting the error: "*undefined method `user' for #*"

## EDIT

Here's my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

 # This is a class method, callable from SessionsController
 # hence the "User."
 def User.create_with_omniauth(auth) 
   user = User.new()
   user.provider = auth["provider"]
   user.uid = auth["uid"]
   user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
   user.save
   return user
  end

  has_one :userprofile
  has_many :exercises
  has_many :weeklyweights
end
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: I assume Activity does not belong_to a user? You do not show that model here, but instead of act.user, just call "user" within the calor_burned method (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

Rails will automatically provide you the accessor to navigate to the user, from an instance of exercise.  In your `calor_burned` method you should be able to do user.id or user_id.

If those methods are not available, then confirm that class User mentions `has_many :exercises` and do you have a migration that sets up the two tables correctly?  Confirm that in your database, exercise has a column called "user_id" and it should be a foreign key over to the users table.